# Cron 'catalogrule_apply_all' locks cron 'indexer_all_invalid' and catalogsearch_fulltext keeps processing Magento 2.3.5

Tags: indexer, magento-cron, magento2.3.5, cronjobs

Took me quite some time to debug this. Every night (default) at 0:00 *catalogrule_apply_all* is run by cron, and resets all indexes for all store.
As a consequence *catalogserach_fulltext* is launched (takes about 8 minutes in my store).

In the meantime, new crons run, and logs begin:

```
main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: indexer_reindex_all_invalid [] []
```

At first five items, but after a day, it's about 60 of these, every minute. And catalogsearch_fulltext is then processing constantly. If it finished, another reindex is started again. Probably, because the *all invalid* index doesn't work anymore. *indexer_reindex_all_invalid* does not come back in action again.

The system does not unlock *indexer_reindex_all_invalid* once this error occurs.

If I do a grep I then see that the cronjob cron:run seems to hang and for about 20 minutes I have cron.php called at least twice.

```
[USER]+ 11321  0.0  0.0   4340   724 ?        Ss   10:09   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /[PATH]/public_html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /[PATH]/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log

[USER]+ 11325 60.2  4.8 590908 197924 ?       R    10:09  10:14 /usr/bin/php /[PATH]/public_html/bin/magento cron:run

[USER]+ 12542  0.0  0.0   4340   772 ?        Ss   10:26   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /[PATH]/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /[PATH]/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log

[USER]+ 12544 57.0  2.1 484272 88712 ?        R    10:26   0:01 /usr/bin/php /[PATH]/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

All crons work perfect, normally - no single cron missed in cron_schedule.
I can reset the indexing by truncating all _cl tables, resetting mview_state version_id, truncating cron_schedule. Manual reindex and flush cache.

Everything works perfectly (also indexer_reindex_all_invalid) untill the next time *'catalogrule_apply_all* is launched. I tested this by adding this manually to cron_schedule.

But now? I don't know what to do anymore, hopefully you have an answer.

The error is thrown by /vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php
I wouldn't know if this needs updating or adjustment.

Additional info

- I do not have any catalog rules. Tried making one and deleting again, no difference.
- I'm using Elasticsearch plugin by Mirasvit, Magento 2.3.5 on a cloudways server. Using Redis for sessions. (don't think it is Mirasvit related).
- In env.php I have 'lock' set to 'db', I think just default settings.
- I've set all cronjobs in config->system for seperate process to 'no'.
- Migrated site from 1.9.x to 2.3.5

It is just the *catalogrule_apply* all that is messing up things. Does anyone have a suggestion?